# Load native libraries in an Eclipse RCP application on Linux

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application that uses some native libraries via JNI. These are shared libraries that dynamically link to each other. On Windows I put these libraries (as `*.dll` files) next to the RCP launcher executable (`*.exe`) file and load them via `System.load("<absolute file path>")`. This works great, as the location of the launcher seems to be added to the `java.library.path` so that dynamic linking between the libraries works.

On Linux, I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. The location of the launcher is not added to the `java.library.path`. When I start the application from the terminal after setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable it works:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
./myApp
```

The location `.` is the added to the `java.library.path`. Is there a better way to do this? I want the users to just double click the launcher.

Setting `-Djava.library.path=.` in the `myApp.ini` file does also not work. I see it in the installation details but I still get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable way to find libraries is not using `java.library.path` at all but finding them via Java code and load via `System.load()` instead of `System.loadLibrary()`. You can apply whatever logic you want for finding the native library (although it's probably best trying not to be too clever) and you could fall back to trying `java.library.path` if your mechanism fails.

This will only work of course if the library doesn't depend on other libraries that might not be found.