# Can't find .dylib file after changing `java.library.path`

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I created a `.dylib` file that I want to load using JNI and I can't get the Java program to find it.

I programmatically checked for the value of `java.library.path` and it was:

```
/Users/potato/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
```

When I placed my `.dylib` file in one of these folders my Java program detected and loaded the `.dylib` file with no problems, but when I tried to change `java.library.path` to include the path to my desktop folder and placed the `.dylib` file on my desktop, the program couldn't find it.

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/Users/potato/Desktop:" + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
System.loadLibrary("winfnc");

output:
/Users/potato/Desktop:/Users/potato/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no winfnc in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Is there a way I can make the program find the `.dylib` file in any folder I want, or better yet in it's own `.jar` file and load it successfully?

**EDIT:** one answer offers a solution that uses the command line, but I'd like to be able to launch the application by double clicking the executable `.jar` file and not have to worry about any technicalities.

There is an option to add VM arguments in Eclipse, but they are only used when launching the program from Eclipse and not by directly opening the runnable `.jar` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.library.path` can't be changed from inside the program. You can set the property but it's value is only used on VM startup, and it will not be read again. You have to set it with `-D`

See also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304696/2543253

Comment: Thanks, the console command worked. However I want to send the program to other people (non-programmers) so they can use it easily without needing anything beyond the `.jar` executable file. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: To my knowledge there's no way to achieve that with your existing code, i.e. using `loadLibrary`. You would have to add a custom launcher or a script for startup. But if you change your code to find the library yourself with whatever logic you want and then use `load` with the library's full path instead of `loadLibrary`, you won't need `java.library.path`

Comment: I was already thinking about stuff like re-launching the application with `Runtime.exec()` and the VM arguments as soon as the program is opened, was too busy thinking about clever solutions and missed the simplest thing lol